# LLM SQL Agents and few shot learning

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I want to use sql Agent together with few shot examples.
I followed this example: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/qa_structured/sql#extending-the-sql-toolkit

However, I want to use VertexAI instead of the OpenAI ones.

I changed the example only on 2 places:

```
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
```

```
agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm=llm,
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    extra_tools=custom_tool_list,
    suffix=custom_suffix,
)
```

I encounter the following error when running the create_sql_agent():

````
__root__
  Invalid prompt schema; check for mismatched or missing input parameters. {'agent_scratchpad', 'input'} (type=value_error) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Modify the custom_suffix variable like below. It worked for me.

```
custom_suffix = """
    I should first get the similar examples I know.
    If the examples are enough to construct the query, I can build it.
    Otherwise, I can then look at the tables in the database to see what I can query.
    Then I should query the schema of the most relevant tables.
    This is the input
        {input}
    Check the below conversations for next steps input
        {agent_scratchpad}
```

"""